# (ORACLE) Is there any difference between using a compressed table and one that's not?

Tags: oracle

I am wondering whether using a compressed table gives you a difference outcome when it comes to the dataset itself or time taken, compared to the original table that's not being compressed.

I compressed 80GB table into 20GB-ish and worrying whether this compressed table gives me a difference result if I use this table later.

```
< ALTER TABLE XXXX MOVE COMPRESS FOR QUERY HIGH >
```

Emperical testing does not give me any difference result other than time taken but just checking.

Comment: The output is exactly the same, it just may get a bit slower.

Comment: It would be **very** strange if compression results in different dataset (which essentially means it *breaks the data*). It would be pointless, why should someone use this if it acts this way?

Answer (score 0):

No, compression does not change the results. It changes how the data is stored in binary form within the datafiles, but unless you are trying to read the files directly outside of Oracle (and nobody should be doing that) you don't care about that... when Oracle reads it and you select it you'll see it the same form you're used to no matter how it is stored physically.

HCC compression like Query High breaks up the table into medium-sized row-major CUs (compression units) and within each of those stores column-major data (column A of all rows, then column B of all rows, etc..). This allows for much better compression than you can get with row-major storage. When you query it, Oracle will reassemble a row-major format as you retrieve it so that it functions identically to normal block storage.

It is intended to be fully invisible to applications, so you shouldn't need to bother with how the data is stored physically as you program. In fact, most tables with compression have a mixture of compressed and uncompressed blocks. In Exadata, you can have a table with a mixture of every kind of compression (AH, AL, QH, QL, OLTP, Basic, etc.). Obviously we're not supposed to care. Only your DBA should be paying attention in order to manage space utilization and (sometimes) tweak performance behind the scenes.